# Using select sub inside UPDATE query

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

The following select statement works fine.

```
SELECT *
FROM [VoiceflexBilling].[dbo].[FEBU17_OWH07579_Calls - TEST] A
WHERE EXISTS   (SELECT 1
               FROM [BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[CLIMapping] B
               WHERE A.CustomerCLI = B.CLI AND A.CustomerCLI = '84422881')
```

However, when I wrap it in a CASE statement, as below

```
UPDATE [VoiceflexBilling].[dbo].[FEBU17_OWH07579_Calls - TEST]  
SET [VoiceflexBilling].[dbo].[FEBU17_OWH07579_Calls - TEST].[CustomerCLI] =  

CASE WHEN

SELECT *
FROM [VoiceflexBilling].[dbo].[FEBU17_OWH07579_Calls - TEST] A
WHERE EXISTS   (SELECT 1
               FROM [BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[CLIMapping] B
               WHERE A.CustomerCLI = B.CLI AND A.CustomerCLI = '84422881'))>1 

THEN 'X' ELSE 'Y' END
```

It fails with the following error

"Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS"

Comment: I'm guessing it should be `select count(*)`... Select * returns a resultset, and you try to compare that to a scalar value...

Answer (score 3):

use "top 1"

```
UPDATE [VoiceflexBilling].[dbo].[FEBU17_OWH07579_Calls - TEST]  
SET [VoiceflexBilling].[dbo].[FEBU17_OWH07579_Calls - TEST].[CustomerCLI] =  

CASE WHEN

SELECT top 1 *
FROM [VoiceflexBilling].[dbo].[FEBU17_OWH07579_Calls - TEST] A
WHERE EXISTS   (SELECT 1
               FROM [BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[CLIMapping] B
               WHERE A.CustomerCLI = B.CLI AND A.CustomerCLI = '84422881'))>1 

THEN 'X' ELSE 'Y' END
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find a `CustomerCLI` number in `[BillingReferenceData].[dbo].[CLIMapping]` table and want update with `X` or `Y` values in `[VoiceflexBilling].[dbo].[FEBU17_OWH07579_Calls - TEST]` table?

You need to use `SELECT COUNT(1)` inside the `CASE` statement.